# PHP escaping complex string in echo

Tags: php, escaping, echo

I am new at this php+HTML5+jquery mobile trying to build a web app with mysql connection.

Somewhere along the way... I use a php file to "generate" a HTML file containing 3 select boxes, where the user will have to choose a day of the month in order to continue.
I designed the destination page using javascript + HTML all went well, then I echoed the entire page in a php file (that I call+process somethings in order to receive the page).
The problem I have is with escaping a string I suppose. 
I mean, if I comment these lines, the page works (not as it should, but at least the page gets shown). If I do not comment them, the jquery shows an alert saying "Error loading page"

The html that works just fine is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Select</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
</head>
<body>
<span id="day-select">
<select id="day">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function LastDayOfMonth(Year, Month) {
    return new Date( (new Date(Year, Month+1,1))-1 );
  }            
var nextmonth = new Date();
nextmonth.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
nextmonth.setMonth( nextmonth.getMonth() + 1 );
var nextziua = nextmonth.getDate();
var ultimazidt = LastDayOfMonth(nextmonth.getFullYear(), nextmonth.getMonth());
var ultimazi = ultimazidt.getDate();
var ziuaselect = nextziua;
var count = ultimazi;
var ziua=1;
while(ziua <= count){
   if(ziua == nextziua){
     document.write('<option value="'+ziua+'" selected="selected">'+ziua+'</option>');
   }
   else{
     document.write('<option value="'+ziua+'">'+ziua+'</option>');
   }
ziua++;
}
</script>
</select>
</span>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

So, the above html file... works just fine, but when I try it from an echo in a PHP file, all goes to hell right at this line:

```
document.write('<option value="'+ziua+'" selected="selected">'+ziua+'</option>');
```

I mean:

```
echo '  <html>';
echo '  <head>';
echo '  <title>Select</title>';
echo '  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>';
echo '  </head>';
echo '  <body>';
echo '  <span id="day-select">';
echo '  <select id="day">';
echo '  <script type="text/javascript">';
echo '  function LastDayOfMonth(Year, Month) {';
echo '  return new Date( (new Date(Year, Month+1,1))-1 );';
echo '  }            ';
echo '  var nextmonth = new Date();';
echo '  nextmonth.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);';
echo '  nextmonth.setMonth( nextmonth.getMonth() + 1 );';
echo '  var nextziua = nextmonth.getDate();';
echo '  var ultimazidt = LastDayOfMonth(nextmonth.getFullYear(), nextmonth.getMonth());';
echo '  var ultimazi = ultimazidt.getDate();';
echo '  var ziuaselect = nextziua;';
echo '  var count = ultimazi;';
echo '  var ziua=1;';
echo '  while(ziua <= count){';
echo '  if(ziua == nextziua){';
echo <<<EOT
document.write('<option value="'+ziua+'" selected="selected">'+ziua+'</option>');
EOT;
echo '  }';
echo '  else{';
echo <<<EOT
document.write('<option value="'+ziua+'">'+ziua+'</option>');
EOT;
echo '  }';
echo '  ziua++;';
echo '  }';
echo '  </script>';
echo '  </select>';
echo '  </span>';
echo '  <br><br>';
echo '  </body>';
echo '  </html>';
```

So this code is generating the contents of a SELECT box, with day numbers 1-30, 1-31 or 1-29 depending on the month. Also it makes "selected" the current day.
Again... all goes fine when doing it directly in HTML, but when I try to echo it... everything stops. because of that document write.
I tried escaping single quotes or escaping double quotes. Same result. That's why I adopted the heredocs method. But as it seems it is still useless for my problem.
I paid attention to the heredocs syntax: 
- no spaces after

```
<<<EOT
```

- no spaces after final EOT;
- The last one (EOT;) is on a new line
  Still, nothing works.
  Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
  Any help will be appreciated.
  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a solution for this "escaping escaped" text. Also, I separated the HTML from PHP (seems to be a widely known and recommended practice). So my code looks like:

```
<?php
 $idviz = $_POST['idvisit'];
 // other php code
?>
<html>
<head>
....
</head>
<body
 <!-- and now the html code for the page, and whenever I need parts/variables from php I just insert it in the middle of the HTML code using <?php $idviz; ?>  or other variables-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was interested in a solution for using a string that has ' and " inside, and on top of that the string would be enclosed in ' or " to be usefull in a syntax like in an echo. If you know what I mean... Sadly I did not see any solution for that, and my poor attempt using heredocs <<< did not enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Add document.close(); just before the  tag.

Comment: I solved it by removing it from php. I mean, I gave up using echo for it. I just stoped php before the HTML begins with ?> and started again after it with <?php.